# generate:doctrine:crud generate templates at app/Resources/view/myentity (out of my bundle)

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I have just run `generate:doctrine:crud`, but I'm a bit surprised because the templates are created at `app/Resources/views/myentity/`.

Since the `Myentity` is inside a bundle I'm creating, it would be better for me to get the generated templates at the `MyBundle/Resources/views` folder.

1. Why the templates are generated at the first folder?
2. Should I copy the generated templates to `MyBundle/Resources/views` to be a part of my bundle?

Comment: just copy them over to your bundle thats how I do it :) you will have to then update your controllers so let them know the new location of your views

Comment: agree with @Baig , you can copy them to your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something new ? 
I found this behavior ... disturbing.
Any chance i can use `generate:doctrine:crud` and get the generated crud's views in my `src/VendorName/MyBundle/Resources/MyEntity` ... like it used to be ?

Thanks.